# How do I turn each tile in a tile map into its own .png image?

Tags: image

For example, this image contains 32px x 32px tiles, exactly 64 to precise. However, I would like to get 64 separate images from this tileset instead of having a tile map.

[image: tileset]

Comment: 64 applies 8x8 tiles, and you are saying that tile size is 32px x 32px. The image supposed to be squared, but the posted image is rectangular. Can you draw the desired 64 tiles over the image? In case it's just a simple splitting into patches, I am sure you can find an existing answer.

Comment: Did you have any success with my answer?

Answer (score 1):

Use **ImageMagick** in the shell on macOS, Linux or Windows like this:

```
magick TBZqU.png -crop 32x32 t-%03d.png
```

and you'll get 64 PNG images called:

```
t-000.png through t-063.png
```

---

Depending what you plan to do with the images afterwards, you may want to add `+repage` after `-crop 32x32` to make them *"forget"* where they used to be in the larger image. Of course, omit the repaging if you wish to reassemble the tiles later.